# How to get rows in mysql from set of chracter match with any column string?

Tags: mysql

```
Table_A
=====================
id|prod_name|cat_id
------------------------
1 | Abc     |1,2,5,6,11
------------------------
2 | Xyz     |11,12,6,5
-----------------------
3 | Mno     |6,9,8,10
....

.....
.
.
...........
```

Above from "Table_A", I get the row which have cat_id are in 1,2,8 any of the the category id in "cat_id" column.

For example :

```
SELECT * FROM Table_A WHERE (cat_id LIKE '%1%' || cat_id LIKE '%2%' || cat_id LIKE '%8%');
```

result Should be like:

```
id|prod_name|cat_id
------------------------
1 | Abc     |1,2,5,6,11
-----------------------
3 | Mno     |6,9,8,10
```

Is this possible in mysql in single query. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

First things first: you probably **shouldn't** keep your data denormalized like that. This breaks 1NF. Consider storing a connection between `Table_A.id` and `cat_id` in a junction table. This would also speed up your lookup time.

Meanwhile, using [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) should get you going:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  Table_A
WHERE
  FIND_IN_SET('1', cat_id) > 0 OR
  FIND_IN_SET('2', cat_id) > 0 OR
  FIND_IN_SET('3', cat_id) > 0;
```

This will return any of the row that contains any of the following value within the `cat_id` column: 1, 2 or 3.